# asp.net Authorization: location and IPrincipal.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, authorization

### Scenario

I'm using a Custom `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` to do asp.net authorization.  I set the `Principal` and `Identity` during the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event using an `IHttpModule`.

The web.config looks approximately like the following:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow verbs="GET,POST" roles="domain\group"/>
    <deny verbs="*" users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="~/admin/user_search.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow verbs="GET,POST" roles="admin"/>
      <deny verbs="*" users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

### The Problem

When making a request the `IPrincipal.IsInRole` method gets called once to check `domain\group` but doesn't get called again to check the `admin` role.  What is causing this?  Do I have the `location` syntax incorrect or is there a deeper issue?

### Notes

I thought initially that the web.config in the admin directory was overriding the web.config in the root directory, but I've tried removing it altogether as well as using it for the `location` element.  Neither have worked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the tilde (~) at the start of paths for <location> elements, as they are not interpreted there. In your example, path="admin/user_search.aspx" should be correct.